# How do I event delegate this filtered jquery object

Tags: jquery

I have this JQuery object returned from a filter call which I attach an event to like so.

```
  visibleCascadeParentCheckbox = $('.checkbox[data-cascade]:not(.hidden)').filter(function(){
      return !$(this).parents('td').hasClass('nested')
  });

  $(visibleCascadeParentCheckbox).on('change', function() {...});
```

But I need to do event delegation on it like so

```
 $('.table').on('click', ****selector from visibleCascadeParentCheckbox****, function() {..});
```

Comment: Will you potentially need different selectors for each element in  visibleCascadeParentCheckbox? Or is this just one element in the end?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean..I'm confused because i'm not sure if `VisibleCascadeParentCheckbox` can return a selector. It is a list of checkboxes which was fine for attaching events to but doesn't work to event delegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to perform the filter-check in the event handler:

```
$('.table').on('click', '.checkbox[data-cascade]:not(.hidden)', function() {
    if ($(this).parents('td').hasClass('nested')) return; // exit!
    // your code...
});
```

NB: there is no use in reusing the *visibleCascadeParentCheckbox* selection you have, since the table may have changed, making the selection outdated. You would not benefit from the more dynamic character of event-delegation.

Comment: Ah Thanks! This makes perfect sense. I was confused because I thought I had to make a callback inside a callback but you have made it very simple and clear that I just combine them into 1 callback!

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each element in your `visibleCascadeParentCheckbox` array and get the string of classes for each one. Then you can take that string, replace the spaces with a comma and period to select the next class, and so on. We slice at the delegation point to remove the first comma.

```
var classes = "";
visibleCascadeParentCheckbox.forEach(function(checkbox) {
    classes = classes + ',.' + $(checkbox).prop('class').replace(' ', ',.');
});

$('.table').on('click', classes.slice(1), function() {..});
```

Comment: This is not giving the desired behaviour. There might be other classes on these elements that have nothing to do with being selected or not, yet you take them all into consideration. Furthermore, this does not take into account the potential future addition/removal of the `nested` class (cf. filter condition in the question).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your elements have a class like  for example "someClass", then you can:

Add the data to the dom and add this code:

```
$('.table').on('click', ".someClass", function() {..});
```

Comment: This just moves the question to how to manage the addition and removal of that class in relation the specific conditions specified in the question. Without a specification on how to do that, this is not really an answer to the question.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, it would have worked but I can't actually insert a new class into my code that way without breaking it because I clone it from a hidden table...hence i need to filter based on parent.

Comment: @trincot I don't agree with that. OP asked how he could bind and delegate an event. I provided an answer with modified conditions but the answer is still relevant to the question.

Comment: @Phil, Hopefully you got a diffirent perspective on a possible alternative soloution, glad I could help:)